Define route for some protocols
I'm on windows 10.
My default gateway is blocking ICMP, but if I change the route to some specific one (which pass through one VPN), ping is working. I can change ping to specific IP with route add the-ip MASK 255.255.255.255 10.1.1.1
The problem is that it only works for one specific IP. I want to do it for the full ICMP protocol.
How can I change the route for the full protocol?

You can't do quite what you're asking. Most ICMP messages (such as "destination unreachable" messages unrelated to ping) are generated by the routers and servers that you're talking to (or through), and there's no way to tell those devices to send their ICMP messages via some other route.
IP implementations don't provide a mechanism for routing all outgoing ICMP messages, or even specifically all outgoing ICMP Echo Request packets, a special way.
One thing that might meet your needs, if you really only care about ping, would be to create a Docker container that can only use the VPN route, and do all your pinging from in there, rather than from your host OS. You could maybe even create a shell alias or shell function so that any time you try to invoke the ping command in the host OS, it actually invokes the ping command inside the Docker container instead.
But you really should fix your broken default gateway. If its NAT is so poorly implemented that it can't handle ICMP properly, or if its firewall is so overzealous that it's blocking all ICMP, then it's going to cause problems for much more than just ping. It probably also screws up traceroute (which relies on ICMP "destination unreachable" messages, not Echo Requests/Replies), and it probably also screws up Path MTU Discovery, which also relies on ICMP "destination unreachable" messages coming through.

Thanks for your answer and for ideas. I already told to the manager of the gateway that it's a bad idea to block it, and that he's doing bad work with this, but it said "it's forbidden" -in case of ICMP-
